# Rails 3 - AJAX request

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, view, request

Rename it

**rename.js.erb**

```
alert('start');
$('div.popup').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('rename')) %>');
```

**_rename.html.erb**

```
Some text
```

**in terminal window**
Processing by ArticlesController#rename as
...

Rendered articles/_rename.html.erb (0.3ms)
Rendered articles/rename.js.erb (2.3ms)

This is my current set up for the AJAX request. I'm still getting this error message **Missing template articles/rename **. I don't understand why, I think everything should be set alright... 
jQuery library is loaded. The `alert` window in JS file don't jump...
Could anyone help me, please, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the full terminal output for that request? I'm interested in where `Rendered articles/_rename.html.erb (0.3ms)` is coming from and what it's being processed as since you simply wrote "...".

The only thing I can think of is that your file isn't named correctly.

`ArticlesController#rename` would look for `rename.html.erb` and not a partial like `_rename.html.erb`.

Comment: There is only `Started GET "/articles/rename" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Sep 26 22:44:36 +0200 2011`, then only SQL queries. If I rename the file from `_rename.html.erb` on `rename.html.erb`, so the error message is out, but the part of page is not load as javascript, but as HTML. The alert message is not loaded - still.

Comment: Please post the **full** output. Especially the part with `Processing by ArticlesController#rename as ...` without the ellipsis. Also, how are you triggering this call to the articles controller to respond with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering _render.html.erb explicitly as a partial within your js file. Rails might be getting confused with the (almost) conflicting names of your views.

In **rename.js.erb**

```
$('div.popup').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'rename')) %>');
```

Or try renaming the partial other than rename.

Comment: Or it actually looks like they are getting loaded properly.. maybe you need to use `jQuery` instead of `$` in your jQuery? I've had to do that before. `jQuery('div.popup').html('<%= escape_javascript(render('rename')) %>');`